Simplifying the inverse normal cdf of an affine transformation of the normal cdf
I want to simplify expressions of the form $\Phi^{-1}(a*\Phi(x)+b))$. A general result would be nice, but if it's helpful, I'm particularly interested in two cases:

$0<a<1$, $b=0$.
$a=(1-b)$, $0<b<1$.

The problem comes from numerical over/underflow issues, i.e., cases where $\Phi(x)$ is very close to 0 or 1. It seems to me that a substitution trick might work here, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

What makes you think that there is a simplification? Maybe one can examine the behavior of the function as $a,b$ changes.
